# how to create an array of objects from a string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to read a string value of this

```
[Screen Size]{27 inch}[/Screen Size][Colour]{Silver}[/Colour][Screen Size]{21 inch}[/Screen Size]
```

into an array of this format

```
[
    {type: "Size", names: ["21 inch", "27 inch"]},
    {type: "Color", names: ["Blue"]}
]
```

using javascript

I have tried a few ways of doing this and have yet to come up with a viable solution

My latest try was this

```
var s = [{Name: '[Screen Size]{27 inch}[/Screen Size][Colour]{Silver}[/Colour][Screen Size]{21 inch}[/Screen Size]'}];

var getVariantsForDisplay = function (s) {
    var variations = [];    
    var values =  {type: undefined, names: []}
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        var mergedArray = mergeVariants(mapVariant(s[i].Name))
        variations.push(mergedArray);
    }
    return variations;
}


//mapVariant returns {["21 inch","Silver","27 inch"], ["Screen Size","Colour"," Screen Size"]}
var mapVariant = function(s) {
    var re = /\[([\s\S]+?)\]{([\s\S]+?)}\[\/\1\]/g;
    var variants = [];
    var valueObj = {types: [], names: []};
    var x;
    while ((x = re.exec(s)) !== null) {
        var type = x[1];
        var name = x[2];
        valueObj.types.push(type);
        valueObj.names.push(name);
    }
    return valueObj;
}


//merge variants returns {["21 inch", "27 inch"], type: "Screen Size"}
var mergeVariants = function(s) {
    //if the type is the same as one already in an object, get that object and add the name to the names array
    var variant = {type: "", names: []};
    var variants = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < s.types.length; i++) {
        if(variant.type === "")
        {
            variant.type = s.types[i];
            variant.names[i] = s.names[i];

        } else if(variant.type === s.types[i]){
            variant.names[i-1] = s.names[i];
        }
    }
    return variant;
}
```

As you can see, it's almost there but just falling short as I lose Colour, which should be in it's own object in an array along with Screen Size.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the end result should be؟

Comment: You know, an object with `color` and `size` properties would be a much easier data structure to work with.

Comment: work on this fiddle [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/973mhzxa/).
Your functions do not work properly

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making a rod for your own back with that data structure. Using an object with `color` and `size` keys with the arrays as their values is *much* easier to manage:

```
var arr = [
  '[Screen Size]{27 inch}[/Screen Size][Colour]{Silver}[/Colour][Screen Size]{21 inch}[/Screen Size]',
  '[Screen Size]{17 inch}[/Screen Size][Colour]{Blue}[/Colour][Screen Size]{41 inch}[/Screen Size]'
];

function getVariants(arr) {
    var out = { color: [], size: [] };
    var regex = /{([a-zA-Z0-9 ]*)}/g
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        var myArray;
        while ((myArray = regex.exec(arr[i])) !== null) {
            if (myArray[1].indexOf('inch') > -1) {
                out.size.push(myArray[1]);
            } else {
                out.color.push(myArray[1]);
            }
        }
    }
    return out;
}
```

**OUT**

```
{
  color: ["Silver", "Blue"],
  size: ["27 inch", "21 inch", "17 inch", "41 inch"]
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/a04ps0te/1/)

The reason this is easier to work with is that now you can just use normal object access methods to get to the data: `obj.color` and `obj.size` and loop over the returned array. By using an array of objects with `type` and `names` properties it's a much more longwinded way to get at the data.

For example, to get at the size name values in your data structure requires an array operation to get at the data:

```
var sizenames = arr.filter(function (el) {
  return el.type === 'Size';
})[0].names;
```

And then you need still need to loop over the returned array.

Comment: Yes that would be a good idea, only the reason I used type and names is because I do not know what the actual object data will be at any given time. So using type and names would leave me with known object structure no matter what the data structure is coming in.